# Angularjs + ui-bootstrap modal doesn't work properly

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I want to implement angular-ui modal, into my web application but when I clicked the button the modal doesnt pop out.

Check out this link
http://embed.plnkr.co/MT2fED8BNYZd6h4g4HnS/

The goal is to get the modal pop out as soon as I click the write button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NUreSc9zZgeI0e5GnwAX?p=preview) of your's:-

Couple of mistakes you done:-

- 1) you used ng="BlogApp" it should be ng-app="BlogApp"
- 2) You should send size like `ng-click="blog.modalWrite('lg')"`
- 3) Controller insdie the modal etc

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. How do i implement a createBlog function into modalWrite function ?

Comment: You have to write the create blog function inside the controller of model because modal scope is different from the "BlogController" you cannot call vm,createBlog() there, instead write your logic inside the model Controller for your work.